# Calculations on byte array as on one huge number

Tags: c#, arrays, calculation

Is there some algorithm with which I will be able to treat a byte[] array as one huge number on which I would be able to do mathematical calculations?
Example:

What I have:
 `byte[] tab = new byte[5] {5, 255, 0 ,1 ,62};`

How I want to treat it as:
`52550162 //whole number`

What I want to do with it:
`tab = tab / 2`

What would be the possible outcome:
`{26, 27, 50, 81}`

The outcome can be randomized `{26, 27, 50, 8, 1}` `{2, 62, 7, 50, 8, 1}`, the only thing that I am carrying about is the possibility to do calculations on numbers represented as a byte array.

Comment: [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0) has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-numerics-biginteger-ctor(system-byte())) that takes a byte array but it doesn't work in the way you describe. Perhaps you want something like `var numberValue = BigInteger.Parse(string.Concat(tab));`?

Comment: Something like that but much faster

Comment: Requirements you describe are very confusing. And sample byte arrays are even more confusing - 262 and 508 can't even fit in byte... I don't think there is any library that support such representation of numbers - which is fine, writing one is not too hard as long as you figure out exactly what you want. Asking why code you have is slow/how to speed it up may be a better variant of the question (ideally with benchmark numbers from Benchmark.net)

Comment: My bad, did write values out of the range of the byte. About the code I had there only 2 actions - byte.ToString() ,BigIntiger.Parse() but Im doing it for nearly millions of the bytes so need it faster than that.

Comment: If the intention is to represent numbers bigger than 64bit unsigned - or even smaller since BigInteger.Parse() is so slow, you'll have better luck by converting it to a string and write a custom code to operate on its digits like you would operate by hand on paper.

Comment: The format seems very strange - a `byte` can represent either 1, 2, or 3 digits of the total number - what is that split based upon? Why isn't the input `5,255,0,162`?

Comment: @NetMage Input can not be changed, I am getting it how it is. The thing that can be split how you want its an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how fast this would be. If you could accept the answer as a `Span<byte>` you could speed this up by just using a large buffer instead of doing `Array.Resize` at the end.

Basically, I compute the answer array by dividing along the original source array, carrying any remainder to the right and splitting any values too large due to the carry. I also add in any skipped `0`s from when the division results in too small a number. Once that is done, I resize the answer array.

```
var ans = new byte[tab.Length * 2];
int r = 0; // remainder to carry
int ansIdx = 0;
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < tab.Length; ++j1) {
    var d = tab[j1] / 2;
    if (r == 0) { // no carry (remainder) from previous division
        if (tab[j1] >= 10) { // original byte was two or three digits
            if (d < 10 && j1 > 0) // new byte is one digit - skipped a zero (only add if past first byte)
                ans[ansIdx++] = 0;
        }
        if (tab[j1] >= 100) { // original byte was three digits
            if (d < 100 && j1 > 0) // new byte is one or two digits - skipped a zero (only add if past first byte)
                ans[ansIdx++] = 0;
        }
        ans[ansIdx++] = (byte)d;
    }
    else { // have a carry (remainder) from previous byte
        if (tab[j1] < 10) // original byte was one digit
            ans[ansIdx++] = (byte)(d+5);
        else if (tab[j1] < 100) // original byte was two digits
            ans[ansIdx++] = (byte)(d + 50);
        else { // original byte was three digits; new value must be split in two
            d += 500;
            ans[ansIdx++] = (byte)(d / 10);
            ans[ansIdx++] = (byte)(d % 10);
        }
    }
    r = tab[j1] % 2; // check for carry (remainder)
}
Array.Resize(ref ans, ansIdx);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert the byte array into a string, and then use [`BigInteger.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=net-6.0) to convert it into a numeric value on which you can use arithmetic.

For example:

```
byte[] tab = new byte[5] {5, 255, 0 ,1 ,62};
var numericValue = BigInteger.Parse(string.Concat(tab));
numericValue /= 2;
Console.WriteLine(numericValue);  // 26275081
```

Comment: Yep, tried it, and is tooo slow to do anything useful with it. It is like parsing 10k values per 2-5min I need it in few sec